# Make a field specific to a user

Tags: entities

I would like to make a field that is specific to a single user, similar to a
non-global flag but allowing more field types than just boolean. Is there a way to do this? For example, if User A sets this field on Node B to 5, then User C looks at that node, he won't see User A's value. If User C then edits the field to another value, then he will see that value instead, and User A will still see his value of 5.

Comment: By "specific to a single user," do you mean that only a single user can edit that field for that user only?

Comment: @PatrickKenny No. I mean that everyone has their own copy of the field that doesn't affect anyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my understanding you want users to be able to set a value on a node which is specific to that particular user. This sounds much like a relationship between the user and the node, so my suggestion would be to look into the [Relation module](http://drupal.org/project/relation). I believe that module would let you achieve this functionality.

I have not used this module so I am afraid I can't help you with details at this point.

Comment: Yes, that is what I want. Interesting…

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can add fields to the user entity with the Field API to

*Admin > Config > Account settings > Manage fields*

The variety of field types are available and each user has their own field value

Comment: Sorry, I must not have explained my problem very well. See my comment on the question.

Comment: Same answer, each user entity has their own 'copy' of the field and it's value.

Comment: Sorry. That's still not what I mean. I want the field on a *common* entity, similar to the d.o subscribe button on issues (which uses the flag module), but of a different field type than boolean.

Comment: @Gaelan Reading your question this looks to be the correct answer. If you consider the answer to be incorrect you should clarify your question with a use case for instance. Explaining what you want to achieve is often helpful.

Comment: @enzipher Edited question to add an example.